# set-spphrase asks for confirmation even if -confirm switch is not used

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

We were trying to set passphrase in sharepoint via powershell cmdlet.

When we mentioned the switch -confirm in the following line, it asked for confirmation

```
Set-SPPassPhrase -PassPhrase $passphrase
```

Then we removed -confirm switch as we passed password in the script itself [though it is security risk , for test environment they needed it] but still it is asking for confirmation. Whether confirmation is by default?

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$passphrase = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPass#$#@" -asPlainText –Force 

Set-SPPassPhrase -PassPhrase $passphrase
```

How to bypass confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (can't test it...)

```
Set-SPPassPhrase -PassPhrase $passphrase -confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 0):

Cmdlet developers can declare what the impact of their cmdlet is, Low, Medium, or High.  In your session, there is an automatic variable `$ConfirmPreference`, which sets the level at which you will be automatically prompted for confirmation, even if you don't pass `-Confirm`

Most cmdlets offer a `-Force` switch which will skip all confirmation, but it doesn't seem like `Set-SPPassPhrase` has one.  You can try explicitly setting `-Confirm:$false`

You can also try setting `$ConfirmPreference = 'None'`

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/15/confirmpreference.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204629(v=vs.85).aspx